# Real analysis measure and continuous

Tags: real-analysis

$\mathscr M$ is a measure iff it is continuous from above.Why?

Comment: Hi. If you show your progress or thoughts, you are much more likely to get help. As it stands, very few people will want to do everything for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So let $\mathscr M' = \bigcup_{\mathscr F \subseteq \mathscr E \text{ countable}} \sigma(\mathscr F)$, we will prove $\mathscr M' = \mathscr M$.

First note, that for every countable $\mathscr F \subseteq \mathscr E$ we have $\sigma( \mathscr F) \subseteq  \sigma(\mathscr E) =  \mathscr M$, hence also $\mathscr M' \subseteq \mathscr M$.

For the other inclusion we will prove that $\mathscr M'$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathscr E$, as $\mathscr M$ is the smallest such, we will obtain $\mathscr M \subseteq \mathscr M'$.

- For $E \in \mathscr E$, $\{E\} \subseteq \mathscr E$ is countable and $E \in \sigma\{E\} \subseteq  \mathscr M'$. So $ \mathscr E \subseteq  \mathscr M'$.
- Let $ \mathscr F \subseteq  \mathscr E$ be countable, then $\emptyset \in  \sigma(\mathscr F) \subseteq \mathscr M'$.
- Let $A \in \mathscr M'$ be given, then there is a countable $ \mathscr F \subseteq  \mathscr E$ with $A \in \sigma( \mathscr F)$. But then $\complement A \in \sigma( \mathscr F)$, as the latter is a $\sigma$-algebra, and hence $\complement A \in \mathscr M'$.
- Let $A_i \in \mathscr M'$ for $i \in \mathbb N$. For each $i$ there is a countable $\mathscr F_i \subseteq \mathscr E$ with $A_i \in \sigma( \mathscr F_i)$. Now set $\mathscr F := \bigcup_{i\in \mathbb N}  \mathscr F_i$. $\mathscr F$ is, as a countable union of such, a countable subset of $\mathscr E$ and we have $A_i \in \sigma(\mathscr F_i) \subseteq \sigma(\mathscr F)$ for each $i$. As $\sigma(\mathscr F)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N} A_i \in \sigma(\mathscr F)\subseteq \mathscr M'$.

Comment: thank you very much from this complete answer!thanks again!